# How to draw projectile motion path in c# .NET Framework console app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console, physics, projectile

### GitHub link: https://github.com/pthdaniel/ProjectileMotion/tree/master

Hey, I was working on a project where my app should calculate the datas with the **initial velocity, angle and height** of the motion, and now my only problem is with the path the projectile makes. I had an idea to make a 2D string array to simulate it, but either the idea itself or my calculations are incorrect. For the array I round the double type datas and then cast them to integers.

```
public Canvas(int height, int width)
    {
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        board = new string[height+1, width+1]; //indexing needs more space

        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                board[i, 0] = "|";
                board[height - 1, j] = "-";
            }
        }
        board[height - 1, 0] = "O";
        board[(int)Math.Round(Program.p.Y0), 0] = "+";

        for (int j = 1; j < width; j++)
        {
            board[Program.p.OtherPosition(j), j] = "+";
        }
    }
```

Here is the constructor of my Canvas class which fills up my string[,] board. The **Program.p** is the projectile itself, which has attributes like **y0**, which is the initial height. The **OtherPosition** takes in the **j** to calculate, where should the method place the * character, where the **x position = j**. Like this:

```
public int OtherPosition(int position)
    {   
        y = y0 + v0y * (position / (2 * v0x)) - (g / 2) * Math.Pow(position / (v0x * 2), 2);

        return (int)(Math.Round(Program.p.Ymax, 1) * 2)+1- 2 * ((int)Math.Round(y));
    }
```

The canvas generation is the following:

```
static void GenerateCanvas(Projectile p)
    {
        int height = (int)(Math.Round(p.Ymax,5)*2);
        int width = (int)(Math.Round(p.Xmax,5)*2);
        board = new Canvas(height, width);
    }
```

The *2 multiplier is there for the bigger size of the whole biard itself.
Can somebody help me to smoothen the path? Sometimes there are * characters underneath each other, which I have no idea how. Or what's another way of doing it?

Comment: so what "is" wrong?

Comment: The path is not at all smooth, and sometimes there are stars underneath each other which I have no idea how could happen